# How to modify TEXT style in text('TEXT').appendTo('body');

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, galleria

In this bit of code, how can I modify the style of 'TEXT'?

```
}).text('TEXT').appendTo('body');
```

This is part of a longer code. TEXT is a link, when you click on it images open in fullscreen (it's part of galleria). However, the TEXT doesn't behave as a link (ie. no hover effect etc.), it is only defined by body { } in the CSS file.

How can I add the appropriate CSS class?

Thanks a lot!

And the full code:

```
<script>

 Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js');
Galleria.run('#galleria');

 $('<a>').click(function(e) {

Galleria.configure({trueFullscreen:false});
Galleria.ready(function(){this.enterFullscreen();});

  }).text('Switch to fullscreen').appendTo('body');

</script>
```

Comment: $('<a>', {'class': 'your classes'})..... But it should display as a link at least, but maybe you have a css reset stylesheet that removes hover effects. You can also set the text of the element like this: $('<a>', {'text': 'Switch to fullscreen', 'class': 'your classes'})

Comment: why don't you just append .html('<a class="yourClass">Switch to fullscreen</a>').appendTo() instead of .text().appendTo() ?

Comment: if you wish to just replace the text of the <a> and add a new class to this, why not using .addClass()? or using the idea from Alex Ackerman.

Comment: all your suggestions work - thanks a lot! one more thing, when my cursor hovers over the link, it doesn't convert into a "hand" as it usually does when a link is selected. instead it shows that symbol that is shown when you can input text (the "i-beam"). why is that and how can you change it? thanks again!

Comment: i solved the cursor problem by adding "cursor:pointer;"!

Answer (score 1):

`.text('Switch to fullscreen').appendTo('body').css("color","blue").hover(function() {$(this).css("color","violet");}, function() {$(this).css("color","blue");});`

Just add this jquery chain with your code. css adds style to the object and hover function is called when you enter and leave the text.

Karthik